# "Keyword not supported: provider" connecting to Access db on VS08

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, .net-3.5, database-connection

I'm trying to connect a DataGridView to an access 2000 database on Visual Studio 2008.

I keep getting the "Keyword not supported: provider" error, as I'm fairly new to windows development on .Net I don't know if I'm doing it right.

Here's the code:

```
Try
    Dim strConn As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Contingencia\Carga_sap.mdb;User Id=admin;Password=;"
    Dim strQuery As String = "SELECT ..."
    Dim dataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(strQuery, strConn)
    Dim table As New DataTable()
    table.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
    dataAdapter.Fill(table)
    bsLista.DataSource = table
    GridListado.AutoResizeColumns(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCellsExceptHeader)
Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
End Try
```

Thanks in advance

EDIT: I just needed to change the Data Adapter to OLE:

```
Dim dataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(strQuery, strConn)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should be using `OleDbDataAdapter` instead of `SqlDataAdapter`. It's trying to read the connection string as a SQL Server connection string.

Comment: Doh! you're absolutely right, sadly the system says I need 15 rep to vote your post as helpfull :(